# How to generate large text in OpenAi by ignoring stop sequence?

Tags: openai-api

I wanted to generate large text in openAi but the problem arise with the stop sequence. It only generates a few sentences for a topic. Is there any way I can bypass the stop sequence for openAI?

Answer (score -3):

You should increase `Maximum length` parameter for this, the higher the value you use the larger text you will get.

> `max_tokens`: integer, Optional, Defaults to 16.
>
> The maximum number of tokens to generate in the completion.

The token count of your prompt plus max_tokens cannot exceed the model's context length. Most models have a context length of 2048 tokens (except for the newest models, which support 4096).

See [the official docs](https://beta.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions/create#completions/create-max_tokens) for more information.